# How to post data to a website, store cookies, then get another page

Tags: python, cookies, flask, mechanize

I've tried solving the problem using Mechanize, but I couldn't get it to work.

A website only allows access to the data if cookies are sent after login.  I need to do the following:

1. Log in using POST to a page
2. Store cookies
3. Access protected page

Comment: Please be specific. What is the website? What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of just asking us to code it for you, you should show us what you have already tried to do, and then we can help you with fixing the problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution using Mechanize.  Cookies are managed by `mechanize.Browser`.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()   
resp = br.open('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['username'] = username
br['password'] = password
response = br.submit()
time.sleep(1)
resp_second = br.open('https://secretwebpage')
print resp_second.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Session in [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).  From the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also **persists cookies across all requests** made from the
>   Session instance.

Here's how a log in and subsequent request *might* look:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session(verify='my_cert_file.crt')
r = s.post('https://secure-site.com/login', data={
    'username': my_username,
    'password': my_password,
})
# logging in sets a cookie which the session remembers
print s.cookies
r = s.get('https://secure-site.com/secure-data')
print r.json()
```